# returning pointer to a pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to return a pointer to a pointer from a function.

I have the following function

```
char **foo() {
 const char **bar;
 ...
 return bar;
}
```

and I get the following warning:

```
warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

what am I missing?

Comment: You need to decide, is it `const`, or is it not `const`. Can't have both...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't jsut cast away the const qualifier like that. It points to pointers to const chars. You can however:

```
 const char **foo() {
   const char **bar;
   ...
   return bar;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`bar` is declared as `const char **` but you are returning `char **`

Answer (score 1):

That's because the function `foo` returns `char **`, while `bar` is of type `const char **`.